# boto3 get KMS tags with lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kms

I'm trying to get the attached tags on specific CMK how can I do that?, I tried with `kms_client.list_aliases` I get the alias info but not it's tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `list_resource_tags` function, which

> Returns a list of all tags for the specified customer master key (CMK).

See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.list_resource_tags

**Request**

```
response = kms_client.list_resource_tags(
    KeyId='string',
    Limit=123,
    Marker='string'
)
```

**Response**

```
{
    'Tags': [
        {
            'TagKey': 'string',
            'TagValue': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'NextMarker': 'string',
    'Truncated': True|False
}
```